# modal inside a modal (delete confirmation)

Tags: interaction-design, user-expectation, users, modal

I have a View/Edit button which shows the details ofuser in a modal when clicked. In modal it has Save and delete buttons. When they click on delete button the user will be deleted. Before they delete, I want to show a delete confirmation. But How would I show that?

I feel it's not a good practice to show a modal inside a modal. Or Is it okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What size is the first modal? In some cases (thinking Visual studio online), the modal occupies almost the entire screen real estate. In this case, I don't think it would be a problem to add a small modal. The user is already immersed in the modal.

If the modal is of moderate size, you could simply substitute the current modal by the deletion confirmation modal. In this case, you need to have a message that refers explicitly to the specific item they're going to delete: Delete item ABCD? - Cancel - Confirm, rather than Delete this item?  - Cancel - Confirm, as they would have lost the context to know what "this item" means.

Comment: The first modal does not occupy the entire screen, it will be in the middle, half size of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

What are the consequences of deleting for the user? Is it permanent?

Eventually, users are going to make a mistake, regardless of if they're warned. Undo can help mitigate the negative consequences of that mistake.

If you can, look to support "undo" instead of popping a warning to confirm. Confirmations are intrusive by nature, and rather annoying.

> "Whenever we have the opportunity to throw away work, the computer
>   must allow us to undo our actions." - *[Never Use a Warning](https://alistapart.com/article/neveruseawarning)*

If you must use that modal, could you change the content within the first window so that the user isn't changing contexts twice?